# CakePHP Media Plugin Thumbnails

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.1

Does anyone familiar with the [Media Plugin](https://github.com/bmcclure/CakePHP-Media-Plugin) know how to generate different sizes of uploaded images?  I've not been able to find any documentation here or on github.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin that replacement de meioupload the name of plugin is Upload plugin 2.0 
https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload

Comment: I only had to add Ploymorphic and Generator Models to the actsas variable within the parent model, sounds complicated but it's really not.  Thanks for the link though.

Comment: Or use https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage which is a lot more advanced than this upload plugin.